# How to print number from 1 to 4 (in X format) in such a way that for every line of number 4 is the middle point?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am a computer science student, I spent the whole day finding logic in this pattern can you please find the logic behind the output and provide me in java code?

This is the output I want:

[image: it is the java output i want to print]

Comment: "I spent the whole day finding logic in this pattern" I suppose you have something to show for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a matrix with total number of rows and cols fill it with spaces then fill it with numbers , N-index-1 gives the corresponding mirror index of each index by iterating N times we can fill all the numbers at once mirroring row starts filling it from left bottom corner mirroring col starts filling it from right bottom and mirroring both fill it from right bottom

```java
import java.util.*;

public class slide {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        var N = sc.nextInt();
        var R = 2*N-1;
        var C = 2*N-1;
        char[][] matrix = new char[R][C];
        for(int row = 0 ; row < R ; row++){
            for(int col = 0 ; col < C  ;col++){
                matrix[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
        for(int index = 0 ; index < N ; index++){
            matrix[index][index] = (char)(index+1+'0');
            matrix[index][C-index-1] = (char)(index+1+'0');
            matrix[R-index-1][index] = (char)(index+1+'0');
            matrix[R-index-1][C-index-1] = (char)(index+1+'0');
        }
        for(int row = 0 ; row < R ; row++){
            for(int col = 0 ; col < C  ;col++){
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask **and answer** homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Your heart may be in the right place, but answering this kind of zero-effort question will only encourage people making them, and we don't really want that

Comment: got it sorry for that